# Can $ \lbrace \cap_{i\in J} A_i \rbrace_{J\subset \mathbb{N} , |J| = \infty} $be uncountably infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given countable collection $\lbrace A_i \rbrace$ of subsets $[0,1]$,can the collection

$$ \lbrace \cap_{i\in J} A_i \rbrace_{J\subset \mathbb{N} , |J| = \infty} $$
be uncountably infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Just look at all the intervals with rational endpoints. This is a countable collections, but for each $r\in[0,1]$ you can find a sequence of intervals with rational endpoints such that $\{r\}$ is the intersection of that sequence.

Comment: then collection $\Big\lbrace  \lbrace r  \rbrace \Big\rbrace $ becoms countably infinite, not uncoutably infinite, doesn't it?

Comment: Why do you think it's now countable?

Comment: because set of rational numbers is countable

Comment: Does the fact that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers mean that the real numbers are countable?

Comment: Oh, I see, every real number can be constructed, not only rational numbers.. my negligence.